# How can I hide elements once they are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

If have an array oData.Con which has 3 objects in it.
On page load these 3 objects are shown on my page. What I want to do is remove them completely. I want to hide/remove the elements from the array.

I tried setInterval and setTimeout but these only work in chrome consistently. In IE the element is loaded and then disappears. I don't want the user to see them at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(function(){
        jQuery("#a").find('div').first().hide();
        jQuery("b").find('div').first().hide();
        jQuery("c").find('div').first().hide();
    }, 0);
}) ;
```

Is there a way to hide elements as soon as they exist so that the user never "sees" the elements.

Comment: Yes, but that would require hooking into whatever is creating them or adding some css.

Comment: you should post the HTML for this. I see `jQuery("#a")` which tells me that you have an id of that name, yet you're not doing it for the other two.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is there a way to hide elements as soon as they exist so that the user
>   never "sees" the elements.

Yes, include an initial declaration of:

```
display: none;
```

in your CSS stylesheet.

**Eg.**

```
#a div,
#b div,
#c div {
display: none;
}
```

> how can i get the first div though. `#a div` = 2 div elements and i want
>   to hide the first one

In this case, you would need:

```
#a div:first-of-type {
display: none;
}
```

or

```
#a div:nth-of-type(1) {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) how can i get the first div though. #a div = 2 div elements and i want to hide the first one

Comment: #a div:nth-of-type(1){
    display: none;
   } doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

You could hide them by default using the display `none` with `:first-child` to hide just the first `div` :

```
#a>div:first-child, #b>div:first-child, #c>div:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps.

```css
#a>div:first-child,#b>div:first-child,#c>div:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
  <div>a1</div>
  <div>a2</div>
  <div>a3</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id='b'>
  <div>b1</div>
  <div>b2</div>
  <div>b3</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id='c'>
  <div>c1</div>
  <div>c2</div>
  <div>c3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works in chrome but not IE and firefox. any other solutions? :) thnaks for your response btw

Comment: this works in chrome but not IE and firefox. In IE and firefox it is not consistent. the elements are visible.any other solutions? :) thnaks for your response btw.

Comment: Already tested in IE 11.0 and Firefox 45.0 which version are you running? check [:first-child Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

Comment: same ones as you. My IE will work only if the page loads and i wait a little bit then it works. otherwise it loads incorrect results

Comment: I see, not sure if you could post a snippet or fiddle of your HTML/CSS to make you're implemented the solution in the right way. have you tried the snippet in my answer in other browsers?

Comment: is tehre a way to set the css once the element loads

Comment: Yes using jquery you could use `$('#a>div:eq(0)').css('display','none')` for example.

Comment: This doesnt hide the elemtns. They appear when the page loads.

Comment: Like i already said we've to see how you implement the code in your side, since as you could see the snippet works just fine. you could try it in othe browsers.